# How to upload "Binary" data through "oneNote API"

Tags: c#, uwp, binary, onenote

I need to upload multiple images to oneNote through "oneNote API", but I don't know how to write binary to code.

Here's the code in my code:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", await Auth.GetAuthToken(provider));

string imagePartName = "imageBlock1";
StringBuilder simpleHtml = new StringBuilder();
simpleHtml.Append("<html lang=\"zh-CN\">\n");
simpleHtml.Append("<head>\n");
simpleHtml.Append("<title>" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + "</title>\n");
simpleHtml.Append("<meta name=\"created\" content=\"" + DateTime.Now.ToString("o") + "\" />\n");
simpleHtml.Append("<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html;charset=utf-8\" />\n");
simpleHtml.Append("</head>\n");
simpleHtml.Append("<body data-absolute-enabled=\"true\" style=\"font-family:Microsoft YaHei;font-size:11pt\">\n");
simpleHtml.Append("<img src=\"name:"+ imagePartName + "\" alt=\"a cool image\" width=\"500\"/>");
simpleHtml.Append("</body>\n");
simpleHtml.Append("</html>");

var createMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, apiRoute + "/pages")
{
    Content = new MultipartFormDataContent
    {
        {
            new StringContent(simpleHtml.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "text/html"), "Presentation"
        }, //Here is the HTML data

        //How to add "binary" data here
    }
};

response = await client.SendAsync(createMessage);
```

Looking forward to everyone's reply!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `MultipartFormDataContent` you can convert your binary data to Base64 string ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8373729/how-to-convert-a-binary-string-to-base64)).
Drawback of this is the amount of characters you need to transfer.

There're several methods in `MultipartFormDataContent` that concerns 'stream'. It would be worth to look into those.