# Twitter Oauth 1.0 Signature Creation, how to convert "binary string" to base64

Tags: javascript, oauth, twitter-oauth, oauth-1.0a

As of right now, I am in the process of creating a signature for OAuth 1.0 for Twitter.
Im following [this](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/oauth-1-0a/creating-a-signature).
I've ran into a small problem at the end.

They have

```
84 2B 52 99 88 7E 88 7602 12 A0 56 AC 4E C2 EE 16 26 B5 49
```

And they manage to create

```
hCtSmYh+iHYCEqBWrE7C7hYmtUk=
```

Their explanation is to Encode the "binary string" to base64.

I saw in this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8373729/how-to-convert-a-binary-string-to-base64) that i basically need to decode hex and then encode base64 to get from

```
84 2B 52 99 88 7E 88 7602 12 A0 56 AC 4E C2 EE 16 26 B5 49
```

To

```
hCtSmYh+iHYCEqBWrE7C7hYmtUk=
```

And it worked in the [online calculator](https://ostermiller.org/calc/encode.html), so now I need to implement it to javascript, the Base64 encode works correctly and looks like that:

```
Buffer.from("ExampleString").toString('base64')
```

However the Hex Decode seems to be the problem
I got the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21647928/javascript-unicode-string-to-hex).
This is my Hex Decoder

```
String.prototype.hexDecode = function(){
  var j;
  var hexes = this.match(/.{1,4}/g) || [];
  var back = "";
  for(j = 0; j<hexes.length; j++) {
      back += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(hexes[j], 16));
  }

  return back;
}
```

I get a different string when I use "my" Decoder and the online calculator, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

answer found [here](https://imagineer.in/blog/authorizing-twitter-api-calls-in-javascript/)

```
function oAuthSignature(base_string, signing_key) {
    var signature = hmac_sha1(base_string, signing_key);
    return percentEncode(signature);
};
```

```
var jsSHA = require('jssha');
function hmac_sha1(string, secret) {
    let shaObj = new jsSHA("SHA-1", "TEXT");
    shaObj.setHMACKey(secret, "TEXT");
    shaObj.update(string);
    let hmac = shaObj.getHMAC("B64");
    return hmac;
};
```

```
function percentEncode(str) {
  return encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/[!*()']/g, (character) => {
    return '%' + character.charCodeAt(0).toString(16);
  });
};
```

If someone is willing to explain the answer, feel free because i'd love to understand it.